# Optional variables and set membership in MiniZinc

Tags: set, minizinc

I have a variable, that should only have a value under certain conditions, so it needs to be an optional variable, I suppose. If that condition is met, the optional variable should be restricted to elements of a set.

The problem is, that MiniZinc does not seem to like optional variables and sets.

How can this be rewritten, so that MiniZinc does not complain?

```
enum TYPES = { TYPE1, TYPE2 };
enum SUBTYPES = { SUBTYPE1, SUBTYPE2, SUBTYPE3, SUBTYPE4 };
var TYPES: mytype;
var opt SUBTYPES: subtype; % if "opt" is removed, it works

constraint mytype=TYPE1 -> subtype in { SUBTYPE1, SUBTYPE3 };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your model is almost correct, but is missing the handling of the optional part of `subtype` in your constraint. Because `subtype` is not guaranteed to exists, we cannot directly say that it has to be in the set `{SUBTYPE1, SUBTYPE3}`. Instead, we have to (1) force the value of `subtype` to exist and (2) then ensure that its value is within the given set.

We can force an optional value to exist by using the `occurs` intrinsic. Its value, on the other hand can be influenced using the `deopt` intrinsic. The constraint thus becomes:

```
constraint mytype=TYPE1 -> (occurs(subtype) /\ deopt(subtype) in { SUBTYPE1, SUBTYPE3 });
```